# Create Bash Script to give the terminal output of logged in users (who)

Tags: bash

I´m trying to create a bash script to create a output of "who"-command for:

1. all users (with no parameter)
2. for a single user (with parameter)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Loginoutput!"
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then echo "No parameter given. Logged in users:"
COUNTER=$(who|wc -l)
while [[ "$COUNTER" -ne 0  ]] && IFS=" " read -r Benutzername Terminal Datum Uhrzeit IP <<< $(who);
do
echo -e "Benutzer: $Benutzername\nTerminal: $Terminal\nDatum: $Datum\nUhrzeit: $Uhrzeit\nIP: $IP"
COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER - 1`
done


else
echo "$i parameters given"
who | awk -v usr="$1" 'BEGIN { if(usr=="") { usr="^.*$" } else { usr="^"usr"$"} } $1~usr { printf "Benutzer:%s\t on \t %s\n",$1,$2 }'
fi
```

<s>In the #-commented part i tried to run the script with ./script user1, user2.
But I don´t know to grep a line of a special user.</s> Maybe anyone can help me.
Another problem is, that the first if clause in the while part reads only the first line of who.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk would be a good candidate for this:

```
who | awk -v usr="$1" 'BEGIN { if(usr=="") { usr="^.*$" } else { usr="^"usr"$"} } $1~usr { printf "Benutzer:%s\nTerminal: %s\nDatum:%s\nUhrzeit:%s\nIP:%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }'
```

Pipe who through to awk. Pass the parameter in as a variable usr. At the start of execution (BEGIN) check if usr is empty. If it is, set usr to regular expression ^.*$ otherwise set to ^usr$. Pattern match against user and print the lines formatted as required.

Comment: Thx for your help.
Any Idea how to fix `while [[ "$COUNTER" -ne 0  ]]` part, that every line will be readed and not only the first line?

Comment: The solution should print every line, there is no need for counters

Comment: Without my counter I´m getting an endless loop of the first line of who ;)

Comment: You don't need any other code, just the one awk statement,